# Parse array of hash to javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, parsing

In Rails, I'd like to parse an array like below to JSON:

```
[{:title=>"eltitulo", :start=>"2014-06-12", :end=>"2014-06-14"}]
```

I have tried to use `@myarray.to_json`. How can I do it?

Comment: The to_json will do the conversion from ruby to json. I can't quite get what your problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want a JSON representation of a ruby array. You're on the right track with calling `.to_json`.

```
[1] pry(main)> a = [{:title=>"eltitulo", :start=>"2014-06-12", :end=>"2014-06-14"}]
=> [{:title=>"eltitulo", :start=>"2014-06-12", :end=>"2014-06-14"}]
[2] pry(main)> a.to_json
=> "[{\"title\":\"eltitulo\",\"start\":\"2014-06-12\",\"end\":\"2014-06-14\"}]"
```

As you can see my `.to_json` call has turned the ruby array into a JSON string. Now if you want to get this JSON string into JavaScript you'll need to output it into your script block with ERB:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  my_objects = jQuery.parseJSON(<%=raw @myarray.to_json %>);
</script>
```

The `jQuery.parseJSON()` bit assume you're using jQuery, and comes from [this StackOverlfow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object).

You may also want to look into using e.g. the [gon gem](https://github.com/gazay/gon) for passing data from your controller into your javascript.

Comment: Thanks, my friend. I finally did it. I post my code now.

Comment: You're welcome. If this solution worked for you, please accept the answer so others know the question is answered.

Comment: I think this code `my_objects = jQuery.parseJSON(<%=raw @myarray.to_json %>);` will be converted to something like this: `my_objects = jQuery.parseJSON([{"title":"eltitulo","start":"2014-06-12","end":"2014-06-14"}]);`.

So, if the string is safe (no user input part in it), you can use `my_objects = <%=raw @myarray.to_json %>;` or you can use `my_objects = jQuery.parseJSON(<%=raw @myarray.to_json.inspect %>);`